# In React, when should I create a custom component

Tags: reactjs, components

I am new to React (just created some simple pages). I am wondering when should I create custom component? like below on facebook docs:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Avatar pagename="Engineering" />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Comment: Here is a good guide about this from React docs itself: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make your components stateless (the state of app should be moved to highest place possible in component hierarchy, or even better to a flux store). While making those components stateless you will learn to divide them along the way.